# How do I print out elements in a multimap ONLY n times

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, multimap

My multimap has an int as a key and a string as the value. The key is the number of times a word has occurred and the value is the word itself. I figured that if I loop through the multimap with my iterator at rbegin and rend, I can just loop through it ten times rather than until it reaches the end to find the top ten words. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use `std::advance` to find the tenth item (starting from `rbegin`). With that, you get a valid range, and you can process it with the usual algorithms and such:

```
std::map<int, std::string> word_freqs;

auto first = word_freqs.rbegin();
auto last = std::next(first, 10);
```

Now, we can (for example) print out those 10 most common words:

```
typedef std::pair<int, std::string> T;

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, T const &t) { 
    return os << t.second << ": " << t.first;
}

std::copy(first, last, std::ostream_iterator<T>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Of course, for robustness, you'd probably want to include a check that the multimap has at least 10 items first (and probably just use `rbegin()` and `rend()` if it's smaller than that).

Answer (score 1):

Sure! Here's one option:

```
unsigned numTimes = 0;
for (auto itr = myMultiMap.rbegin();
     itr != myMultiMap.rend() && numTimes < kMaxTimes;
     ++itr, ++numTimes) {

    /* Do something with itr */

}
```